# Adding CSS style to table in django with django_tables2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I'm very new to Django. I'm trying to add a CSS style to a table when

```
{% render_table table %}
```

is being run.

The code looks as following:

views.py:

```
def myTable(request):
    table = myDataTable.objects.all()
    filter = request.GET.get('q')
    startDate = request.GET.get('sd')
    endDate = request.GET.get('ed')
    if mail:
        table = table.filter(Q(filter__icontains=filter) &
                         Q(evaluation_date__range=[startDate, endDate])).distinct()
    else:
        table = table.filter(Q(evaluation_date__range=[startDate, endDate])).distinct()
    table = TableView(table)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'myapp/myTable.html', {'table': table})
```

tables.py:

```
class TableView(tables.Table):
      class Meta:
           model = myDataTable
           template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

myApp.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
....
<body>
     {% render_table table %}
```

In `project/static/css/` I have a custom style file `customstyle.css`, but there is no way to make the rendered table use that style.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is your question how to use your custom style, or does the bootstrap style doesn't work?

Comment: The question is how to use my custom style. I want the table to have a custom layout that i have in the css.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to get the correct style for a table I was also rendering via:

```
{% render_table table %}
```

In your tables.py file you can do as follows to set attributes of the table itself (such as its' class):

```
class TableView(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling a table generated by django-tables2 is [explained in the documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html). You can use the default class attributes, or specify custom ones.

In order to use your custom style sheet `customstyle.css` (using the classes mentioned above), you must include it into your template. django-tables2 doesn't do that for you, but you can learn how to do that from the [django tutorial part 6](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html):

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}" />
```

You have to adjust names and paths according to the location in your project.